# Hourly run dag in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

My Dag

```
{
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 10, 7, 1, 00),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'catchup_by_default': False,
}

dag = DAG('Hourly_test_2', schedule_interval='0 * * * *', default_args=default_args)
```

It runs every hour, but it shows 1 hour less in tree view graph. Example in tree view graph time show 8AM but the actual time is 9 AM.  How to sync both times?

Job should run every hour and hour should match with a current hour in the Tree view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not a time synchronization problem, it is due to the start_date and schedule_interval, airflow by default calculates how many times it should have been executed from start_date until the current date and start a DAG Run for any interval that has not been executed check [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup).

In your case the start date is 7:01 and according to your schedule_interval the execution intervals are 8:00, 9:00, 10:00 ...

This is why there is a DAG Run at 8:00, you can disable this behavior by default by setting the parameter catchup = False in your dag definition.

```py
dag = DAG('Hourly_test_2', catchup=False, schedule_interval='0 * * * *', default_args=default_args)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how airflow schedules. Check this part of the scheduler documentation.

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run
>   stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In
>   other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has
>   ended.
>
> Let’s Repeat That The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval
>   AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html

Comment: I have the same config but the dag is not triggered hourly. Any suggestions. I assume if i set the hourly config at 9:30 the next dag run should be triggerred at 10:29 ?!

Comment: That's correct. It should still runs hourly as long as your `schedule_interval` is set to hourly.  If your DAG have to run at 9:30, then you need to adjust `start_date` to 8:30.

Comment: That makes sense. But my dag run is triggered every (T-1):59. I am seeing that the dag run for 12:00 pm is being triggered at 1pm ?! Anu idea why ?  in default_args `datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)`

Comment: That is exactly how Airflow schedules. Please check the quote closely. "The job is started once the period it covers has ended." If schedule is hourly, an execution for 12:00pm will run at 1pm, when the period "hour" has ended (12:00 + hour = 1:00).